# What is observable, observer and subscribe in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs5

I am learning angular and i got confuse in these observable, observer and subscribe
thing. So please explain.

Answer (score 109):

Here is a simple visual to see the difference:

[image]

As seen above ... an **Observable** is a stream of events or data. They are often returned from Angular methods, such as the `http.get` and the `myinputBox.valueChanges`.

**Subscribing** "kicks off" the observable stream. Without a subscribe (or an async pipe) the stream won't start emitting values. It's similar to subscribing to a newspaper or magazine ... you won't start getting them until you subscribe.

The subscribe method takes in an **observer**. An observer has three methods:

- The method to process each time an item is emitted from the observable.
- The method to process any error that occurs.
- The method to clean up anything when the observer completes. This last one is seldom used when working with Angular's observables.

(And I agree ... trying to see the forest through the trees of the docs is quite a challenge. I understand they are working to improve them.)

Comment: yes  and for anyone researching this, @DeborahK in not just a random poster, she has a bunch of material on Pluralsight on this topic so IMHO this is likely to be a good and usable analogy.   Also, I believe the paradigm may have had origin in one of the famed GOF design patterns   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 24):

Trying to explain with a really simple example:-

1. **Observable** is like a youtube channel of someone else. (( It uploads new videos(data) from time to time, **so it is a data source** for you))
2. Your youtube account is an **Observer**
3. Your youtube account **(Observer)** can only get notifications about whether someone else's youtube channel **(Observable)** has uploaded a new video **(has new data)** or made a livestream **(new event)** only if you have **subscribed** to that channel

**(Observer subscribes Observable to listen for new data/any event)**

where observable is a data source, subscribe is like a method/function , Observer is generally on your side

Answer (score 4):

An **Observable** can be thought of as various data sources(ex: (userInputs)Events, HttpRequests etc).

here creating our custom observable.

```
    var observable = Observable.create((observer: any)=>{
       observer.next("Hii")
       observer.next("how are you")
       observer.complete()
    observer.next("This will not send to observer")
});
```

- next() used to emit values to observer
- complete() indicates that completion of observable is notified.

An **Observer** is basically who subscribes to Observable.

```
observable.subscribe(
    (data: any) => console.log(data), // for handling data
    (error: any) => console.log(error), // for handling error
    () => console.log('completed'); // for handling completion
```

);

Here you can learn more about Observable
[http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl80y.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some key points :

1) Definition: "Observable and Observer" is a pattern of message passing from publisher to subscriber.
2) Flow of functionality:

- Observable is created
- Observer subscribe to Observable
- Observable can pass message to observer
- each time, when the observable passes a not a message it is received by Observer

3) Real-time usage of Observable and Observer

- While receiving response from AJAX
- While performing large tasks in client(browser)