# what is difference between observable and subsribe and promise in angular8

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am getting confusion of observable and subscribe and promise in angular 8.How can I easily understand about observable,subscribe,promise. Anyone Can you explain about subscribe with observable? observable work as a data storage? If we use subscribe can we get bunch of value or single value one by one?

Comment: It would be better if you specified *what specifically* you are not understanding.

Comment: @Igor: Can you explain about subscribe with observable? observable work as a data storage? If we use subscribe can we get bunch of value or single value one by one?

Comment: Subscribe + Observable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51520584/1260204

Comment: `If we use subscribe can we get bunch of value or single value one by one` ← Yes and Yes.

Comment: `observable work as a data storage` ← You can cache the result so that way it is only ever fired once using shareReplay. Then all subscribers get the same value every time.

Comment: If you have specific questions about 1 topic please create a new question and be detailed in that question.